Rendering specific views with Twig

I have html files with specific tags under the views folder. I am using Twig for template processing and rendering.
My index.php:
<?php
include("lib/init.php");

echo $twig->render('index.html', $data);
?>

Question:
How can I tell Twig to load a specific html from the views folder and add it to the current index.html rendering?
I am unable to find anything in the documentation, I looked at blocks (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/block.html).
Other details, composer.json:
{
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "8.3.9"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "twig/twig": "^3.10",
        "spomky-labs/otphp": "^10.0"
    }
}


https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#including-other-templates ?

This question is similar to: Twig embed vs include, any reason to use include. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
